# Ionic Creator app: external links do not always work

Tags: android, ios, cordova, ionic-framework, ionic-view

I made an application in Ionic Creator that has a link to an external web address contained within.

[image: How the button looks in the cretor]

However, this link only works sometimes.

- It DOES work in visual studio's Ripple android emulator
- It DOES work in the Ionic View app for iOS
- It does NOT work in the Ionic View App for Android (it acts as if the button is not linked).
- It does NOT work when compiled via `ionic build ios` (it acts as if the button is not linked).

Just in case it'll get brought up: I AM importing cordova-plugin-inappbrowser, creator imports it by default.

Answer (score 0):

When you download the package the imported stuff is lost. Re-import it after downloading it from the creator.